# Custom P3P Agent

Tags: browser, p3p

I want to create a P3P agent to add some functionality to the existing agents but I don't know how to start. I know how to plug the policy to my website but what I really want is to develop simple browser that gets the page and compare the policy to the local preferences.
So, is there any library out there or web services to make me able to retrieve the policy and parse it and hence compare it to the user preferences?

Thanks
fans

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the code for Privacy Bird. It is a P3P extension for IE. It is open source. It only supports IE6, but it should definitely help you get started. I used to work on it some time ago, but it hasn't been updated in a long time.

http://www.privacybird.org/